# Why does Orbeon create such a large org.orbeon.oxf.cache.MemoryCacheImpl object?

Tags: java, caching, out-of-memory, orbeon

I'm running on old version of Orbeon Forms, 3.9.0.rc1.201103220245 CE to be precise. Lately I've regularly seen the JVM running it throwing OutOfMemoryError: Java Heap Space errors. I analyzed a heap dump, and found that an instance of org.orbeon.oxf.cache.MemoryCacheImpl had by far the largest retained size. I've researched, but did not found any bug report associated with it. One thing I found was a post on the Orbeon mailing list that may be related: http://discuss.orbeon.com/Unusually-large-number-of-blocking-threads-td2338846.html . Does anyone know if this issue is fixed in later versions of Orbeon?

Thanks,

-Michiel

Answer (score 0):

Without spending a significant time analyzing the heap dump, it is very hard to say anything conclusive. Orbeon Forms maintains a number of caches, `MemoryCacheImpl` being one of them, and to run efficient it needs fair amount of memory.

In some cases, that might be "too much" memory. If it is a problem, it could be caused by of a bug (memory leak), a problem with the form or application running on top of Orbeon Forms, or something that could be done more efficiently in Orbeon Forms. At this point, there are no open known issues in the "leak" category, but a number of things could be done more efficiently. Quite a few things have already been improved since 3.9, but there is still work to do, and this is one of the items on the [Orbeon Forms roadmap](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/wiki/Orbeon-Forms-Roadmap).

So, I would recommend you try to upgrade to the latest stable version (4.5 as of this writing), see of you're still seeing the same problem. If you are, see if there is anything in your app/forms that could be causing this, see if you can increase the heap size, or reduce the cache sizes.